# Как передать из одного метода в другой коллекцию значений?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане!

У меня довольно простой вопрос. Есть метод в контроллере, который должен возвращать ActionResult. Последние строчки метода выглядят так:

```
List<int> list = (List<int>) Session["myList"];
return RedirectToAction("ListViewer", "ListManager", new { myList = list });
```

Однако, при переходе в метод `ListViewer(List<int> myList)` контроллера `ListManager`, входной параметр остаётся пустым. То есть, при выполнении RedirectToAction значение теряется, хотя я точно знаю, что передаю заполненый лист, что видно в отладке. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так в этом решении и как можно передать коллекцию элементов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RedirectToAction - это не переход "в другой метод контроллера". Это возврат клиенту (браузеру) нового url, который ведет на другой Action. То что вы передаете третьим параметром, становится частью этого url.

Ваш лист приписывается к возвращаемой ссылке в качестве GET-параметра. Ссылка отдается на клиентскую сторону - браузеру. Браузер делает по ссылке новый запрос. Сервер пытается достать из пришедшего запроса данные для параметра myList. И тут возникает пара проблем.

- ASP.NET MVC не умеет преобразовывать списки и вообще сложные вещи в параметры url. Он ограничивается вызовом ToString. Поэтому клиенту отдается не слишком полезная ссылка вида

  ```
  /ListManager/ListViewer?myList=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.Int32%5D
  ```
- При обработке запроса ASP.NET MVC сможет разобрать параметр List. Но только если каждый из элементов списка придет отдельным GET-параметром. С именами `myList[0]`..., `myList[1]`. Ну или хотя бы `[0]`, `[1]`. Т.е. он ждет ссылки вида

  ```
  /ListManager/ListViewer?%5B0%5D=1&%5B1%5D=2&%5B2%5D=3
  ```

Чтобы ее сформировать, ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
var values = new RouteValueDictionary(
       list
           .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
           .ToDictionary(
               key => string.Format("[{0}]", key.index),
               value => (object)value.item
           )
   );

return RedirectToAction("ListViewer", "ListManager", values);
```

Но в вашем случае - это все ненужные костыли. Eсть два гораздо более простых варианта:

- Правильный - вынести общий код из двух действий в отдельный метод. Возвращать и из вашего действия, и из ListViewer результат вызова этого метода. А не редиректить клиента туда-сюда, с данными в адресной строке.
- Чуть менее правильный - сделать редирект на ListViewer без параметров. Ну или с параметром вида `fromSession = true`. ListViewer такой же Action как и текущий. Он точно так же может достать значения из сессии. Нет никакой необходимости перебрасывать их как часть url на клиентскую сторону, а потом обратно.

Comment: Еще можно использовать TempData

Comment: @Ice2burn да, но TempData внутри использует сессию, а у ТС данные и так лежат в сессии

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо вам огромное за такой прекрасный ответ!!!)))

Answer (score 0):

```
return View("ListViewer", list);
```

Comment: а по-другому можно? Просто не хочется каждый раз дублировать все значения для ViewBag, а их не мало. А если мы возвращаем "View", то их надо прописать обязательно. А если редиректимся на экшн, то он и будет их вычислять.

Comment: "ViewBag, а их не мало." - значит самое время пересмотреть их использование в сторону использования специальных классов модели представления

Comment: @ Oleg Sh, можете привести какой-нибудь пример того, о чём говорите в виде кода?

Comment: используйте например класс         public class ZoneElementViewModel
        {
            public int ZoneID { get; set; }
            public string ZoneName { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
            public bool HasPdf { get; set; }
        }
вместо ViewBag.ZoneName, ViewBag.DateCreated....